# Jquery: Change class of Label based on check/uncheck of checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I have series of checkbox (based on user selection), I am using bootstrap CSS and want to change the class of parent (label). The following code sort of works, it changes the class but it should go back to original once unchecked.

HTML Code:

```
   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label for="status" class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" id="status" value="1"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
     </label>
   </div>
```

Jquery:

```
     $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
       if ($(this).prop('checked', true)) {
           $(this).parent().addClass('btn btn-primary');
       } else {
          ($(this).prop('checked', false)); 
           $(this).parent().addClass('btn btn-default');
        }
      });
```

I tried few alternates, toggleClass etc but its not quite right. I am hoping once the user uncheck's it goes back to original class - btn-default.

Here's the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=T34b6tblRc

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: When you give two arguments to `.prop()`, you're SETTING the property, not reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$('input').change(function () {           
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('btn-primary',checked);
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('btn-default',!checked);    
});
```

This will change the classes completely. You dont need to remove the btn class.

```js
$('input').change(function () {           
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('btn-primary',checked);
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('btn-default',!checked);    
});
```

```css
.btn-primary{
    background-color: red;
}

.btn-default{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label for="status" class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" id="status" value="1"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
     </label>
   </div>
```

Comment: This works. My approach works too. Based on your experience, which one do you think is the best practice? I'm always lost with that.

Comment: Your solution is also a nice one! There isn't a big difference between our snippets. I just keep in mind that there is alway the possibility that other people had to work on your code so for my its important to keep it readable. Therefore i'm working with the common single var pattern. That helps to keep the solution clean and readable. @ADASein

Answer (score 2):

Could this work? Let me know to delete my answer if not

```
$('input').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass($(this).is(':checked') ? 'btn btn-default' : 'btn btn-primary'); 
    $(this).parent().addClass($(this).is(':checked') ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read a property, you should only give one argument to `.prop()`. Giving two arguments sets the property to the second argument, it doesn't compare the property with it. So it should be:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('btn btn-primary');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('btn btn-default');
    }
});
```

You can also just use `if (this.checked)`, which is more efficient than creating a jQuery object and calling a method on it.

Comment: This could be the right answer because it's not only showing the solution but also pointing the error. Unfortunately, it has forgotten removing or toggling the current class.

Answer (score 1):

Add the 'btn btn-default' class manually

```
$('input').change(function () {
   var b = $(this).is(':checked');
   $(this).parent().addClass(b?'btn-primary':'btn-default');
   $(this).parent().removeClass(!b?'btn-primary':'btn-default');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code on jsfiddle is blank. Please fix it. I would like to view your code in jsfiddle to see how it works.